# OpenVPN can't ping to server and server side LAN devices

Tags: ip, openvpn, ping

Hi I cannot ping at server and server side LAN devices.

My PC has ip 192.168.9.100

Server ip 192.168.1.171

I ping ONLY From server to client virtual ip 10.8.0.50 (client)

And From PC to SERVER virtual ip 10.8.0.1

Is bridge necessary for me? What I do bad?

I trying to ping at device 192.168.1.4 for example in server side LAN and its unreachable...

I post my config client here:

#

```
# Sample client-side OpenVPN 2.0 config file #
# for connecting to multi-client server.     #
#                                            #
# This configuration can be used by multiple #
# clients, however each client should have   #
# its own cert and key files.                #
#                                            #
# On Windows, you might want to rename this  #
# file so it has a .ovpn extension           #
##############################################

# Specify that we are a client and that we
# will be pulling certain config file directives
# from the server.
client
route 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0
# Use the same setting as you are using on
# the server.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel
# if you have more than one.  On XP SP2,
# you may need to disable the firewall
# for the TAP adapter.
;dev-node MyTap

# Are we connecting to a TCP or
# UDP server?  Use the same setting as
# on the server.
;proto tcp
proto udp

# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
# You can have multiple remote entries
# to load balance between the servers.
remote 80.250.xxx.xxx 22294
;remote my-server-2 1194

# Choose a random host from the remote
# list for load-balancing.  Otherwise
# try hosts in the order specified.
;remote-random

# Keep trying indefinitely to resolve the
# host name of the OpenVPN server.  Very useful
# on machines which are not permanently connected
# to the internet such as laptops.
resolv-retry infinite

# Most clients don't need to bind to
# a specific local port number.
nobind

# Downgrade privileges after initialization (non-Windows only)
;user nobody
;group nobody

# Try to preserve some state across restarts.
persist-key
persist-tun

# If you are connecting through an
# HTTP proxy to reach the actual OpenVPN
# server, put the proxy server/IP and
# port number here.  See the man page
# if your proxy server requires
# authentication.
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]

# Wireless networks often produce a lot
# of duplicate packets.  Set this flag
# to silence duplicate packet warnings.
;mute-replay-warnings

# SSL/TLS parms.
# See the server config file for more
# description.  It's best to use
# a separate .crt/.key file pair
# for each client.  A single ca
# file can be used for all clients.
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\beran.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\beran.key"

# Verify server certificate by checking that the
# certicate has the correct key usage set.
# This is an important precaution to protect against
# a potential attack discussed here:
#  http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm
#
# To use this feature, you will need to generate
# your server certificates with the keyUsage set to
#   digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
# and the extendedKeyUsage to
#   serverAuth
# EasyRSA can do this for you.
remote-cert-tls server

# If a tls-auth key is used on the server
# then every client must also have the key.
;tls-auth ta.key 1

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# If the cipher option is used on the server
# then you must also specify it here.
# Note that v2.4 client/server will automatically
# negotiate AES-256-GCM in TLS mode.
# See also the ncp-cipher option in the manpage
cipher AES-256-CBC

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# Don't enable this unless it is also
# enabled in the server config file.
#comp-lzo

# Set log file verbosity.
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages
;mute 20
```

and my server config here:

```
#################################################
# Sample OpenVPN 2.0 config file for            #
# multi-client server.                          #
#                                               #
# This file is for the server side              #
# of a many-clients <-> one-server              #
# OpenVPN configuration.                        #
#                                               #
# OpenVPN also supports                         #
# single-machine <-> single-machine             #
# configurations (See the Examples page         #
# on the web site for more info).               #
#                                               #
# This config should work on Windows            #
# or Linux/BSD systems.  Remember on            #
# Windows to quote pathnames and use            #
# double backslashes, e.g.:                     #
# "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\foo.key" #
#                                               #
# Comments are preceded with '#' or ';'         #
#################################################

# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
local 192.168.1.171

# Which TCP/UDP port should OpenVPN listen on?
# If you want to run multiple OpenVPN instances
# on the same machine, use a different port
# number for each one.  You will need to
# open up this port on your firewall.
port 1194

# TCP or UDP server?
;proto tcp
proto udp

# "dev tun" will create a routed IP tunnel,
# "dev tap" will create an ethernet tunnel.
# Use "dev tap0" if you are ethernet bridging
# and have precreated a tap0 virtual interface
# and bridged it with your ethernet interface.
# If you want to control access policies
# over the VPN, you must create firewall
# rules for the the TUN/TAP interface.
# On non-Windows systems, you can give
# an explicit unit number, such as tun0.
# On Windows, use "dev-node" for this.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel if you
# have more than one.  On XP SP2 or higher,
# you may need to selectively disable the
# Windows firewall for the TAP adapter.
# Non-Windows systems usually don't need this.
;dev-node MyTap

# SSL/TLS root certificate (ca), certificate
# (cert), and private key (key).  Each client
# and the server must have their own cert and
# key file.  The server and all clients will
# use the same ca file.
#
# See the "easy-rsa" directory for a series
# of scripts for generating RSA certificates
# and private keys.  Remember to use
# a unique Common Name for the server
# and each of the client certificates.
#
# Any X509 key management system can be used.
# OpenVPN can also use a PKCS #12 formatted key file
# (see "pkcs12" directive in man page).
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.key"

# Diffie hellman parameters.
# Generate your own with:
#   openssl dhparam -out dh2048.pem 2048
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\dh1024.pem"

# Network topology
# Should be subnet (addressing via IP)
# unless Windows clients v2.0.9 and lower have to
# be supported (then net30, i.e. a /30 per client)
# Defaults to net30 (not recommended)
;topology subnet

# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

# Maintain a record of client <-> virtual IP address
# associations in this file.  If OpenVPN goes down or
# is restarted, reconnecting clients can be assigned
# the same virtual IP address from the pool that was
# previously assigned.
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging.
# You must first use your OS's bridging capability
# to bridge the TAP interface with the ethernet
# NIC interface.  Then you must manually set the
# IP/netmask on the bridge interface, here we
# assume 10.8.0.4/255.255.255.0.  Finally we
# must set aside an IP range in this subnet
# (start=10.8.0.50 end=10.8.0.100) to allocate
# to connecting clients.  Leave this line commented
# out unless you are ethernet bridging.
;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging
# using a DHCP-proxy, where clients talk
# to the OpenVPN server-side DHCP server
# to receive their IP address allocation
# and DNS server addresses.  You must first use
# your OS's bridging capability to bridge the TAP
# interface with the ethernet NIC interface.
# Note: this mode only works on clients (such as
# Windows), where the client-side TAP adapter is
# bound to a DHCP client.
;server-bridge

# Push routes to the client to allow it
# to reach other private subnets behind
# the server.  Remember that these
# private subnets will also need
# to know to route the OpenVPN client
# address pool (10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0)
# back to the OpenVPN server.
;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0

# To assign specific IP addresses to specific
# clients or if a connecting client has a private
# subnet behind it that should also have VPN access,
# use the subdirectory "ccd" for client-specific
# configuration files (see man page for more info).

# EXAMPLE: Suppose the client
# having the certificate common name "Thelonious"
# also has a small subnet behind his connecting
# machine, such as 192.168.40.128/255.255.255.248.
# First, uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# Then create a file ccd/Thelonious with this line:
#   iroute 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# This will allow Thelonious' private subnet to
# access the VPN.  This example will only work
# if you are routing, not bridging, i.e. you are
# using "dev tun" and "server" directives.

# EXAMPLE: Suppose you want to give
# Thelonious a fixed VPN IP address of 10.9.0.1.
# First uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
# Then add this line to ccd/Thelonious:
#   ifconfig-push 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2

# Suppose that you want to enable different
# firewall access policies for different groups
# of clients.  There are two methods:
# (1) Run multiple OpenVPN daemons, one for each
#     group, and firewall the TUN/TAP interface
#     for each group/daemon appropriately.
# (2) (Advanced) Create a script to dynamically
#     modify the firewall in response to access
#     from different clients.  See man
#     page for more info on learn-address script.
;learn-address ./script

# If enabled, this directive will configure
# all clients to redirect their default
# network gateway through the VPN, causing
# all IP traffic such as web browsing and
# and DNS lookups to go through the VPN
# (The OpenVPN server machine may need to NAT
# or bridge the TUN/TAP interface to the internet
# in order for this to work properly).
;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

# Certain Windows-specific network settings
# can be pushed to clients, such as DNS
# or WINS server addresses.  CAVEAT:
# http://openvpn.net/faq.html#dhcpcaveats
# The addresses below refer to the public
# DNS servers provided by opendns.com.
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

# Uncomment this directive to allow different
# clients to be able to "see" each other.
# By default, clients will only see the server.
# To force clients to only see the server, you
# will also need to appropriately firewall the
# server's TUN/TAP interface.
;client-to-client

# Uncomment this directive if multiple clients
# might connect with the same certificate/key
# files or common names.  This is recommended
# only for testing purposes.  For production use,
# each client should have its own certificate/key
# pair.
#
# IF YOU HAVE NOT GENERATED INDIVIDUAL
# CERTIFICATE/KEY PAIRS FOR EACH CLIENT,
# EACH HAVING ITS OWN UNIQUE "COMMON NAME",
# UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT.
;duplicate-cn

# The keepalive directive causes ping-like
# messages to be sent back and forth over
# the link so that each side knows when
# the other side has gone down.
# Ping every 10 seconds, assume that remote
# peer is down if no ping received during
# a 120 second time period.
keepalive 10 120

# For extra security beyond that provided
# by SSL/TLS, create an "HMAC firewall"
# to help block DoS attacks and UDP port flooding.
#
# Generate with:
#   openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key
#
# The server and each client must have
# a copy of this key.
# The second parameter should be '0'
# on the server and '1' on the clients.
;tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# This config item must be copied to
# the client config file as well.
# Note that v2.4 client/server will automatically
# negotiate AES-256-GCM in TLS mode.
# See also the ncp-cipher option in the manpage
cipher AES-256-CBC

# Enable compression on the VPN link and push the
# option to the client (v2.4+ only, for earlier
# versions see below)
;compress lz4-v2
;push "compress lz4-v2"

# For compression compatible with older clients use comp-lzo
# If you enable it here, you must also
# enable it in the client config file.
;comp-lzo

# The maximum number of concurrently connected
# clients we want to allow.
;max-clients 100

# It's a good idea to reduce the OpenVPN
# daemon's privileges after initialization.
#
# You can uncomment this out on
# non-Windows systems.
;user nobody
;group nobody

# The persist options will try to avoid
# accessing certain resources on restart
# that may no longer be accessible because
# of the privilege downgrade.
persist-key
persist-tun

# Output a short status file showing
# current connections, truncated
# and rewritten every minute.
status openvpn-status.log

# By default, log messages will go to the syslog (or
# on Windows, if running as a service, they will go to
# the "\Program Files\OpenVPN\log" directory).
# Use log or log-append to override this default.
# "log" will truncate the log file on OpenVPN startup,
# while "log-append" will append to it.  Use one
# or the other (but not both).
;log         openvpn.log
;log-append  openvpn.log

# Set the appropriate level of log
# file verbosity.
#
# 0 is silent, except for fatal errors
# 4 is reasonable for general usage
# 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
# 9 is extremely verbose
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages.  At most 20
# sequential messages of the same message
# category will be output to the log.
;mute 20

# Notify the client that when the server restarts so it
# can automatically reconnect.
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

here is client log:

```
Thu Jun 07 11:22:33 2018 OpenVPN 2.4.6 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Apr 26 2018
Thu Jun 07 11:22:33 2018 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
Thu Jun 07 11:22:33 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018, LZO 2.10
Enter Management Password:
Thu Jun 07 11:22:33 2018 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Thu Jun 07 11:22:33 2018 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Thu Jun 07 11:22:34 2018 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Thu Jun 07 11:22:34 2018 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Thu Jun 07 11:22:34 2018 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Thu Jun 07 11:22:34 2018 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
Thu Jun 07 11:22:34 2018 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 5'
Thu Jun 07 11:22:34 2018 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Thu Jun 07 11:22:34 2018 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Thu Jun 07 11:22:34 2018 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]80.250.xxx.xxx:22294
Thu Jun 07 11:22:34 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Thu Jun 07 11:22:34 2018 UDP link local: (not bound)
Thu Jun 07 11:22:34 2018 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]80.250.9.157:22294
Thu Jun 07 11:22:34 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528363354,WAIT,,,,,,
Thu Jun 07 11:22:37 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528363357,AUTH,,,,,,
Thu Jun 07 11:22:37 2018 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]80.250.xxx.xxx:22294, sid=f9d6039e e32e786e
Thu Jun 07 11:22:37 2018 VERIFY KU OK
Thu Jun 07 11:22:37 2018 Validating certificate extended key usage
Thu Jun 07 11:22:37 2018 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Thu Jun 07 11:22:37 2018 VERIFY EKU OK
Thu Jun 07 11:22:39 2018 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 4096 bit RSA
Thu Jun 07 11:22:39 2018 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]80.250.xxx.xxx:22294
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528363360,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0,route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.49,peer-id 1,cipher AES-256-GCM'
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1624
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 interactive service msg_channel=924
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.9.1/255.255.255.0 I=31 HWADDR=58:2c:80:13:92:63
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 open_tun
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 TAP-WIN32 device [Ethernet 2] opened: \\.\Global\{0A8323CA-9328-4637-80F1-F2532A81F33D}.tap
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.21 
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.8.0.50/255.255.255.252 on interface {0A8323CA-9328-4637-80F1-F2532A81F33D} [DHCP-serv: 10.8.0.49, lease-time: 31536000]
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 Successful ARP Flush on interface [4] {0A8323CA-9328-4637-80F1-F2532A81F33D}
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Thu Jun 07 11:22:40 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528363360,ASSIGN_IP,,10.8.0.50,,,,
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 TEST ROUTES: 4/4 succeeded len=4 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528363365,ADD_ROUTES,,,,,,
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 192.168.4.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.49
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 Route addition via service succeeded
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 192.168.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.49
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 Route addition via service succeeded
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 10.8.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.49
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 Route addition via service succeeded
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 10.8.0.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.8.0.49
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 Route addition via service succeeded
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
Thu Jun 07 11:22:45 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528363365,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.8.0.50,80.250.xxx.xxx,22294,,
```

I ADD MY ROUTE TABLE FROM SERVER

```
Výpis trasy k 192.168.9.100 s nejvýše 30 směrováními

  1    < 1 ms    < 1 ms    < 1 ms  192.168.1.254
  2    < 1 ms    < 1 ms    < 1 ms  xxxxxxxxxxxxx router
  3     5 ms     4 ms     4 ms  10.6.8.254
  4     5 ms     *        4 ms  vl23-prg-sit-c6k-vrf-pha-luc-cust.wia.cz [185.33
.139.251]
  5     5 ms     4 ms     4 ms  pha-asr-akro-vrf-luc-cust.wia.cz [80.250.xxx.xxx]
  6     4 ms     *        5 ms  pha-asr-akro-vrf-luc-cust.wia.cz [80.250.xxx.xxx]
  7     *        *        *     Vypršel časový limit žádosti.

IPv4 Směrovací tabulka
===========================================================================
Aktivní směrování:
         Cíl v síti   Síťová maska            Brána        Rozhraní Metrika
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254    192.168.1.171    266
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.2         10.8.0.1     20
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.1.0         10.8.0.1     21
         10.8.0.0  255.255.255.252       Propojené          10.8.0.1    276
         10.8.0.1  255.255.255.255       Propojené          10.8.0.1    276
         10.8.0.3  255.255.255.255       Propojené          10.8.0.1    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0       Propojené         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255       Propojené         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       Propojené         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0       Propojené     192.168.1.171    266
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0       Propojené          10.8.0.1     21
    192.168.1.171  255.255.255.255       Propojené     192.168.1.171    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255       Propojené     192.168.1.171    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255       Propojené          10.8.0.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       Propojené         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       Propojené          10.8.0.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       Propojené     192.168.1.171    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       Propojené         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       Propojené          10.8.0.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       Propojené     192.168.1.171    266
===========================================================================
Trvalé trasy:
  Síťová adresa            Maska    Adresa brány     Metrika
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254  Výchozí
===========================================================================

IPv6 Směrovací tabulka
===========================================================================
Aktivní směrování:
 Rozhraní Metrika Cíl v síti      Brána
  1    306 ::1/128                  Propojené
  1    306 ff00::/8                 Propojené
===========================================================================
Trvalé trasy:
  Žádné
```

I Ping from Client only to 10.8.0.1 I think I need to connect 10.8.0.1 some way to 192.168.1.0 subnet on server?

This is my route table CLIENT:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.1.4 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1  3004 ms   440 ms   357 ms  10.8.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3  ^C
C:\WINDOWS\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
  8...1c 1b 0d e8 8f 9f ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  4...00 ff 0a 83 23 ca ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 31...58 2c 80 13 xx xx ......Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.9.1    192.168.9.100     45
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.5         10.8.0.6    291
         10.8.0.1  255.255.255.255         10.8.0.5         10.8.0.6    291
         10.8.0.4  255.255.255.252         On-link          10.8.0.6    291
         10.8.0.6  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.6    291
         10.8.0.7  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.6    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.5         10.8.0.6    291
      192.168.9.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.9.100    301
    192.168.9.100  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.9.100    301
    192.168.9.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.9.100    301
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.8.0.6    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.9.100    301
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.6    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.9.100    301
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  4    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 31    301 fe80::/64                On-link
 31    301 fe80::94a0:26e:9150:8e91/128
                                    On-link
  4    291 fe80::c816:3134:8cba:8234/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  4    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
 31    301 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: LAN devices at the server’s location most likely do not have a route to the VPN network.

Comment: I dont know how to route them. Please help. For example device 192.168.1.4 how to route to VPN network 10.8.0.0? Thank you so much. Or how to route them in all range?

Comment: You write that your PC has 192.168.1.38 and the server is 192.168.1.171; so they are in the same subnet. So why use a VPN? Or are they different networks that happen to be numbered in the same range? In that case, you will never be able to reach any 192.168.1.* hosts on the remote side as your PC routes that to your local network, not the network on the other end of the VPN connection.

Comment: Hi please forget that pc is 192.168.1.38 right is pc 192.168.9.100

Answer (score -1):

The ports don’t match, between the client and server, which is different. The client is going in on 22294, but the server is listening at 1194.

But, I think maybe uncomment “redirect gateway....”, then for dns option, just use your LAN DNS, usually 192.168.1.1.